# How to parse Response xml in JMeter and send the result as dynamic parameters to another http request

Tags: jmeter

i'm new to Jmeter . I'm getting the response as xml from the server. Now I need to pass the some of the values which i'm getting in the response to the next http request as post parameters . Please suggest me on this .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything external to deal with XML data in JMeter, it provides built-in [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

However you need to learn XPath. Following things may help a lot:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) - a great place to start
- [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) Firefox Plugin - visual XPath evaluator
- [Online XPath Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) Free online XPath Tester

Comment: The both links has been changed. The important are the keywords, according of them I am able to find out the proper pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jmeter extras set this could be what you are looking for
[http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/].

Your test plan could look something like this

test plan
| thread group
| | http sampler
| | | Xpath extractor - configure a variable in here then use the ${_*fifoPut(x)}

| | http sampler 2 - ${*_fifoPop(x)}